# how to exclude "featured" posts from the main loop?

Tags: query-posts, get-posts, featured-post

In a category.php template, I built a function that lists "featured" posts before the main loop. The featured posts are selected using a custom field and get_posts():

```
function list_featured_articles(){
 $featured_posts = get_posts('meta_key=featured_article&meta_value=on&numberposts=10&order=DESC&orderby=post_date');
}
```

My category.php template:

```
echo list_featured_articles();
get_template_part( 'loop', 'category' );
```

It works fine, except that the featured articles are listed also in the category list of articles. 
I would like, from my function, get the featured posts' ID and remove them from the main loop. 
Is there a proper way to do it? I figure i could use a GLOBAL variable storing an array of excluded ids, but i'd like to avoid using Globals for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would be an appropriate use of [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), with a [post custom meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

Since you're *querying* by `meta_key=featured_article&meta_value=on`, you would then *exclude* on the same parameters.

```
<?php
// Setup the custom meta-query args
$exclude_featured_args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'featured_article',
            'value' => 'on',
            'compare' => '!='
        )
    )
 );
// globalize $wp_query
global $wp_query;
// Merge custom query with $wp_query
$merged_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $exclude_featured_args );
// Query posts using the modified arguments
query_posts( $merged_args );
?>
```

That should exclude featured posts from the main loop.

Note: you'll only want to do this in the same context in which you display the featured posts loop.

**EDIT**

From your comment:

> my function is set up so that if there are no "featured" post, it automatically takes the most recent ones and display them as "featured"

Again, you can take whatever method you use to **include** posts in your featured loop, and then use the same arguments to **exclude** the same posts from the primary Loop.

Without knowing what your method is, I can't give a precise answer for how to incorporate it into your excluded-posts argument array.

Comment: this sounds good, but would this makes an additional sql query or would it replace the initial "main" query?

Comment: You should read the Codex link for `query_posts()`, as it answers this question. The `query_posts()` function is used to alter the **primary Loop**.

Comment: Forgive me for not mentioning it directly: my function is set up so that if there are no "featured" post, it automatically takes the most recent ones and display them as "featured". So i can't really take that road (although i'm still interested to know if your answer replaces the query or creates an additional one).

Comment: ok i got it: i adapted your proposal:
In my function i stored the IDs in a global variable.
I then use it in my category.php template like this, before calling the loop:

`$exclude_featured_args = array(
    'post__not_in' => $excluded_posts
 );
$merged_args = array_merge( $wp_query->query, $exclude_featured_args );
query_posts( $merged_args );`

Comment: "*although i'm still interested to know if your answer replaces the query or creates an additional one*"... from my above comment: **The `query_posts()` function is used to alter the primary Loop**. It **alters** the **primary Loop**; it does *not* create a *new* loop.

Comment: Yeah, i posted my comments pretty much at the same time as you :) Thanks for making that point crystal clear!

Your answer sent me on the right track so i'll select it. thanks!